# "BackgroundMoving" Code is not Working in iPhone4S

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am making one game in which i am facing problem when I test my App on Device(iPhone4) the background of it is not working. Like when background image ends BLACKISH BACKGROUND COLOR comes. My Background image size is 460X2880,image name "mars_sample.jpg" (for iPhone4) And code for Background Moving is  :

```
-(void)backgroundmoving:(ccTime)dt 
{     
    static float bk_f=0.0f;

    bk_f -=0.9;
    if (bk_f <= -960*3) {bk_f=0;}
    background.position = ccp( 0,bk_f);    
}
```

When I am loading "460X2880" size image as Background image then it doesn't loads in background AND if it is like of size "460X1192" it loads image in background but Showing BLACKISH BACKGROUND Color on Top of screen.

Below one CODE is for Setting Background image :

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    background = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"staripad.png"];
    background.anchorPoint= ccp(0,0);
    [self addChild:background z:0];
} else {
    background = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"mars_sample.jpg"];
    background.anchorPoint= ccp(0,0);
    [self addChild:background z:0];
    [self schedule:@selector(backgroundmoving:) interval:1/30];
}
```

Please Give me some suggestions, how it will work.
Thanks ALL

Regards,

Tauseef Khan

Comment: isn't the screen on iPhone 480px high (without the status bar) - is that the BLACKISH BACKGROUND at the top of the screen? If not, please add a screenshot to your question :)

Comment: These are the link for Screen Short, For what exactly i am facing problem !!!

http://www.mediafire.com/?s9dh63n3pv3znil

http://www.mediafire.com/?lfdxxrclo365ozj

Answer (score 2):

Check `background.position = ccp( 0, bk_f )` in `backgroundmoving` you are setting the Y value of the coordinate to a fixed value, `bk_f`. I assume that it's the X value that you'd want to change in order to scroll the background image, `background.position = ccp( bk_f, 0 )`.

The parameter `dt` to `backgroundmoving` that I assume is to provide a moving background image is not used.

Make sure that the background view is set to expand to fit it's super view using autosize properties .

Examine the origin in the frame property of your background view - check that it is at the top of your screen.

I'd add a plain UIView behind your background UIImageView and set it's color to green or some other harsh color. That way you could visually confirm the real-estate covered by the views.

Comment: NO, I NOT used XIB to Layout my background. See the code I Provided on Top Where I asked my Question. It's Moving Background and Problem i am facing after some second when Background gets start Moving.

Comment: Actually I am moving my background in PORTRAIT Mode, because of that I code like that. Please see the link of screen short which I provided. ( mediafire.com/?s9dh63n3pv3znil And mediafire.com/?lfdxxrclo365ozj ). Here the background is moving from Top to Bottom.
For that I given condition like this :

background.position = ccp( 0, bk_f )

If you need any more explanation about this , please let me know. Thanks And Waiting for your Reply

Answer (score 1):

```
//in .h file int bk_f=240;

-(void)backgroundmoving:(ccTime)dt 
{     

    bk_f=bk_f-5;    
    if(bk_f<=0)
    {
        background.position = ccp( 240,160); 
        bk_f=240;
    }
    else
    {
        background.position = ccp( bk_f,160); 
    }


}
```